# Execute python shell program at live cd startup?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, operating-system

I was thinking to use Arch linux, but am open to other options.
So what I want is that when Arch Linux boots from a usb, instead showing me the default bash console, it executes a python3 program that I've written.

I need it to execute immediately, I don't want to just have the console.py file stored there (live usb) and have to type python3 console.py, just select boot arch linux, and see my fancy console.

- Boot Screen
- Arch Linux Loading Live USB Screen
- My Console Program

Comment: `init=/usr/bin/python wahtever.py`?

Comment: Set your [`tty1` to autologin](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Automatic_login_to_virtual_console) and specify `-l /path/to/console.py` to `agetty` to make it run automatically. Also make sure to disable X.